# move text on click d3js collapsible trees

Tags: d3.js

I am using the [collapsible tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) in d3js and want to create the functionality that the text of the children will always be on the right hand side of the node and the text  the parent will be on the left hand side.

And this updates every time a node is clicked.

the text attr are set in the chunk below.

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

Comment: And what is your question?  You want the text of the last shown nodes to be to the right?

Comment: yes, but move back to the let when new children are created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are required.  You modify the x position and anchor based just on children being available (and not hidden children):

```
.attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
  return d.children ? "end" : "start"; 
})
```

You also need to move the position to the update selection so it'll do it on redraw:

```
nodeUpdate.select("text")
  .style("fill-opacity", 1)
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
    return d.children ? "end" : "start"; 
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) { 
    return d.children ? -10 : 10;
  });
```

Here's some full running [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/QnTrZRPXa7QWuvBeq3Pd?p=preview).

Stack snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//d3.json("flare.json", function(error, flare) {

  var flare = {"name":"flare","children":[{"name":"analytics","children":[{"name":"cluster","children":[{"name":"AgglomerativeCluster","size":3938},{"name":"CommunityStructure","size":3812},{"name":"HierarchicalCluster","size":6714},{"name":"MergeEdge","size":743}]},{"name":"graph","children":[{"name":"BetweennessCentrality","size":3534},{"name":"LinkDistance","size":5731},{"name":"MaxFlowMinCut","size":7840},{"name":"ShortestPaths","size":5914},{"name":"SpanningTree","size":3416}]},{"name":"optimization","children":[{"name":"AspectRatioBanker","size":7074}]}]},{"name":"animate","children":[{"name":"Easing","size":17010},{"name":"FunctionSequence","size":5842},{"name":"interpolate","children":[{"name":"ArrayInterpolator","size":1983},{"name":"ColorInterpolator","size":2047},{"name":"DateInterpolator","size":1375},{"name":"Interpolator","size":8746},{"name":"MatrixInterpolator","size":2202},{"name":"NumberInterpolator","size":1382},{"name":"ObjectInterpolator","size":1629},{"name":"PointInterpolator","size":1675},{"name":"RectangleInterpolator","size":2042}]},{"name":"ISchedulable","size":1041},{"name":"Parallel","size":5176},{"name":"Pause","size":449},{"name":"Scheduler","size":5593},{"name":"Sequence","size":5534},{"name":"Transition","size":9201},{"name":"Transitioner","size":19975},{"name":"TransitionEvent","size":1116},{"name":"Tween","size":6006}]},{"name":"data","children":[{"name":"converters","children":[{"name":"Converters","size":721},{"name":"DelimitedTextConverter","size":4294},{"name":"GraphMLConverter","size":9800},{"name":"IDataConverter","size":1314},{"name":"JSONConverter","size":2220}]},{"name":"DataField","size":1759},{"name":"DataSchema","size":2165},{"name":"DataSet","size":586},{"name":"DataSource","size":3331},{"name":"DataTable","size":772},{"name":"DataUtil","size":3322}]},{"name":"display","children":[{"name":"DirtySprite","size":8833},{"name":"LineSprite","size":1732},{"name":"RectSprite","size":3623},{"name":"TextSprite","size":10066}]},{"name":"flex","children":[{"name":"FlareVis","size":4116}]},{"name":"physics","children":[{"name":"DragForce","size":1082},{"name":"GravityForce","size":1336},{"name":"IForce","size":319},{"name":"NBodyForce","size":10498},{"name":"Particle","size":2822},{"name":"Simulation","size":9983},{"name":"Spring","size":2213},{"name":"SpringForce","size":1681}]},{"name":"query","children":[{"name":"AggregateExpression","size":1616},{"name":"And","size":1027},{"name":"Arithmetic","size":3891},{"name":"Average","size":891},{"name":"BinaryExpression","size":2893},{"name":"Comparison","size":5103},{"name":"CompositeExpression","size":3677},{"name":"Count","size":781},{"name":"DateUtil","size":4141},{"name":"Distinct","size":933},{"name":"Expression","size":5130},{"name":"ExpressionIterator","size":3617},{"name":"Fn","size":3240},{"name":"If","size":2732},{"name":"IsA","size":2039},{"name":"Literal","size":1214},{"name":"Match","size":3748},{"name":"Maximum","size":843},{"name":"methods","children":[{"name":"add","size":593},{"name":"and","size":330},{"name":"average","size":287},{"name":"count","size":277},{"name":"distinct","size":292},{"name":"div","size":595},{"name":"eq","size":594},{"name":"fn","size":460},{"name":"gt","size":603},{"name":"gte","size":625},{"name":"iff","size":748},{"name":"isa","size":461},{"name":"lt","size":597},{"name":"lte","size":619},{"name":"max","size":283},{"name":"min","size":283},{"name":"mod","size":591},{"name":"mul","size":603},{"name":"neq","size":599},{"name":"not","size":386},{"name":"or","size":323},{"name":"orderby","size":307},{"name":"range","size":772},{"name":"select","size":296},{"name":"stddev","size":363},{"name":"sub","size":600},{"name":"sum","size":280},{"name":"update","size":307},{"name":"variance","size":335},{"name":"where","size":299},{"name":"xor","size":354},{"name":"_","size":264}]},{"name":"Minimum","size":843},{"name":"Not","size":1554},{"name":"Or","size":970},{"name":"Query","size":13896},{"name":"Range","size":1594},{"name":"StringUtil","size":4130},{"name":"Sum","size":791},{"name":"Variable","size":1124},{"name":"Variance","size":1876},{"name":"Xor","size":1101}]},{"name":"scale","children":[{"name":"IScaleMap","size":2105},{"name":"LinearScale","size":1316},{"name":"LogScale","size":3151},{"name":"OrdinalScale","size":3770},{"name":"QuantileScale","size":2435},{"name":"QuantitativeScale","size":4839},{"name":"RootScale","size":1756},{"name":"Scale","size":4268},{"name":"ScaleType","size":1821},{"name":"TimeScale","size":5833}]},{"name":"util","children":[{"name":"Arrays","size":8258},{"name":"Colors","size":10001},{"name":"Dates","size":8217},{"name":"Displays","size":12555},{"name":"Filter","size":2324},{"name":"Geometry","size":10993},{"name":"heap","children":[{"name":"FibonacciHeap","size":9354},{"name":"HeapNode","size":1233}]},{"name":"IEvaluable","size":335},{"name":"IPredicate","size":383},{"name":"IValueProxy","size":874},{"name":"math","children":[{"name":"DenseMatrix","size":3165},{"name":"IMatrix","size":2815},{"name":"SparseMatrix","size":3366}]},{"name":"Maths","size":17705},{"name":"Orientation","size":1486},{"name":"palette","children":[{"name":"ColorPalette","size":6367},{"name":"Palette","size":1229},{"name":"ShapePalette","size":2059},{"name":"SizePalette","size":2291}]},{"name":"Property","size":5559},{"name":"Shapes","size":19118},{"name":"Sort","size":6887},{"name":"Stats","size":6557},{"name":"Strings","size":22026}]},{"name":"vis","children":[{"name":"axis","children":[{"name":"Axes","size":1302},{"name":"Axis","size":24593},{"name":"AxisGridLine","size":652},{"name":"AxisLabel","size":636},{"name":"CartesianAxes","size":6703}]},{"name":"controls","children":[{"name":"AnchorControl","size":2138},{"name":"ClickControl","size":3824},{"name":"Control","size":1353},{"name":"ControlList","size":4665},{"name":"DragControl","size":2649},{"name":"ExpandControl","size":2832},{"name":"HoverControl","size":4896},{"name":"IControl","size":763},{"name":"PanZoomControl","size":5222},{"name":"SelectionControl","size":7862},{"name":"TooltipControl","size":8435}]},{"name":"data","children":[{"name":"Data","size":20544},{"name":"DataList","size":19788},{"name":"DataSprite","size":10349},{"name":"EdgeSprite","size":3301},{"name":"NodeSprite","size":19382},{"name":"render","children":[{"name":"ArrowType","size":698},{"name":"EdgeRenderer","size":5569},{"name":"IRenderer","size":353},{"name":"ShapeRenderer","size":2247}]},{"name":"ScaleBinding","size":11275},{"name":"Tree","size":7147},{"name":"TreeBuilder","size":9930}]},{"name":"events","children":[{"name":"DataEvent","size":2313},{"name":"SelectionEvent","size":1880},{"name":"TooltipEvent","size":1701},{"name":"VisualizationEvent","size":1117}]},{"name":"legend","children":[{"name":"Legend","size":20859},{"name":"LegendItem","size":4614},{"name":"LegendRange","size":10530}]},{"name":"operator","children":[{"name":"distortion","children":[{"name":"BifocalDistortion","size":4461},{"name":"Distortion","size":6314},{"name":"FisheyeDistortion","size":3444}]},{"name":"encoder","children":[{"name":"ColorEncoder","size":3179},{"name":"Encoder","size":4060},{"name":"PropertyEncoder","size":4138},{"name":"ShapeEncoder","size":1690},{"name":"SizeEncoder","size":1830}]},{"name":"filter","children":[{"name":"FisheyeTreeFilter","size":5219},{"name":"GraphDistanceFilter","size":3165},{"name":"VisibilityFilter","size":3509}]},{"name":"IOperator","size":1286},{"name":"label","children":[{"name":"Labeler","size":9956},{"name":"RadialLabeler","size":3899},{"name":"StackedAreaLabeler","size":3202}]},{"name":"layout","children":[{"name":"AxisLayout","size":6725},{"name":"BundledEdgeRouter","size":3727},{"name":"CircleLayout","size":9317},{"name":"CirclePackingLayout","size":12003},{"name":"DendrogramLayout","size":4853},{"name":"ForceDirectedLayout","size":8411},{"name":"IcicleTreeLayout","size":4864},{"name":"IndentedTreeLayout","size":3174},{"name":"Layout","size":7881},{"name":"NodeLinkTreeLayout","size":12870},{"name":"PieLayout","size":2728},{"name":"RadialTreeLayout","size":12348},{"name":"RandomLayout","size":870},{"name":"StackedAreaLayout","size":9121},{"name":"TreeMapLayout","size":9191}]},{"name":"Operator","size":2490},{"name":"OperatorList","size":5248},{"name":"OperatorSequence","size":4190},{"name":"OperatorSwitch","size":2581},{"name":"SortOperator","size":2023}]},{"name":"Visualization","size":16540}]}]};

//  if (error) throw error;

  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
//});


function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1)
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
        return d.children ? "end" : "start"; 
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
        return d.children ? -10 : 10;
      });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
```

Comment: I added the extra line to change the angle of the text depending on the side its on. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `nodeUpdate.select("text")
            .style("fill-opacity", 1)
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
                  return d.children ? "end" : "start"; 
                 })
            .attr("transform", function(d) {return d.children ? "rotate(20)":"rotate(0)"})
            .attr("x", function(d) { 
                  return d.children ? -10 : 10;
                });`